# How to show duplicate Error with Mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

```
`INSERT INTO MYTABLE(FLIGHTNUMBER, ORIGIN, DESTINATION) VALUES (109, "SIN", "KUL")`
```

If FLIGHTNUMBER= 109 and ORIGIN = SIN already present in MYTABLE throw error.

How to write query for checking only two columns value and not for all the columns ?

Comment: Why not add unique index `(FLIGHTNUMBER,ORIGIN)` ?

Comment: nb strings such as SIN need to be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I just showed example for insert query , Question is about how can we check for some column contains same value then throw the error

Comment: This is exactly what  a unique index on the column[s] of interest does.

Comment: What's your objection to creating a unique index?

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments an unique key on `(FLIGHTNUMBER,ORIGIN)` would be enough.

```
alter table MYTABLE add unique key flight_orig(FLIGHTNUMBER,ORIGIN);
```

If you try to insert the same values per FLIGHTNUMBER,ORIGIN an error will be thrown

> Duplicate entry '109-SIN' for key 'MYTABLE.flight_orig'

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/jv0FkQkC)

Another option is using before insert trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_exists BEFORE INSERT ON MYTABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from MYTABLE where NEW.FLIGHTNUMBER=FLIGHTNUMBER and NEW.ORIGIN=ORIGIN)
          THEN 
             SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
              SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Values exists on table';

        END IF;
    END;
```

In this case the error would be,

> Values exists on table

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TT8iiRFC)